# Spring Oauth2 separate resource server configuration

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to configure separate auth and resource servers for oauth2.
I am able to configure authrization server successfully and able to authenticate and generate access tokens. Now I want to configure a resource server which can talk to auth server with api end point to validate the access tokens.
Below is my resource server configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Oauth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter      {


 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("Oauth2SecurityConfiguration before");   
     http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/**").authenticated();
     System.out.println("Oauth2SecurityConfiguration  after");
}

@Bean
public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
}

@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices() {
    final RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
    remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:9000/authserver/oauth/check_token");
    remoteTokenServices.setClientId("clientId");
    remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret("clientSecret");
    remoteTokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    return remoteTokenServices;
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
    authenticationManager.setTokenServices(remoteTokenServices());
    return authenticationManager;
}   
}


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        System.out.println("http.csrf().disable()");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/**").fullyAuthenticated();
        System.out.println("http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()");
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

 @Override
 protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
   return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
 }
}
```

Question :
1. why I AuthenticationManager at resource server while all the authentication is delegated to auth server. (I had to add it to load application context)

Apart from this I am facing below issues.

1. Even though I am not passing authorization headers and access token with the request. It's going through.

   ```
   http GET "http://localhost:8080/DataPlatform/api/v1/123sw/members"
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
   Date: Mon, 19 Oct 2015 19:45:14 GMT
   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   {
   "entities": [], 
   "errors": [], 
   "message": null
   }
   ```
2. The filters are only invoked at once I don't see the logs for following requests. Does it cache authorization somewhere?

I am new to spring oauth Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. I am using

```
spring-security-oauth2 : 2.0.7.RELEASE
spring-security-core   : 4.0.1.RELEASE
java : 1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

The main point make separate endpoints for auth-server and resource-server, that they can services them separately, each his own.
As show bellow "/user/getEmployeesListRole/**" -access through auth-server, "/user/getEmployeesListOAuth2/**" - access through resource-server by token, which generated by  aouth2-server.Also please pay attention that  auth-server and  oauth2-server has the same auth-manager

Configuration of spring-boot aouth2-server, resource-server, auth-server in one spring-boot app

1.Entry Point:

```
/*AuthApplication.java*/
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class AuthApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }}
```

2. Config of aouth2-server:

```
/*OAuth2AuthorizationConfig.java*/
     @Configuration
     @EnableAuthorizationServer
     public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

     private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
     private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceBean")
     private  UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

     @Override
     public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
           clients.inMemory()
                  .withClient("browser")
                  .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                  .scopes("ui", "read:ui", "write:ui");
     }
```

@Override
 public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
          endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
     }
     @Override
     public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
           oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                      .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                      .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
     }}
2.1 aouth2-server auth-request [post with basic auth]:

```
http://localhost:5000/uaa/oauth/token?grant_type=password&scope=ui write:ui&username=user&password=123456&client_id=browser
```

3.Config resource-server:

```
/*ResourceServer.java*/
    @Configuration
       @EnableResourceServer
       class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
         //Here we specify to allow the request to the 
         // url /user/getEmployeesList with valid access token and scope read
         @Override
         public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http.requestMatchers()
                   .antMatchers("/user/getEmployeesList/**")
                   .antMatchers("/user/getEmployeesListOAuth2/**")
           .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('ui')");

      }}
```

4. Config  auth-server:

```
/*WebSecurityConfig.java*/
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

`@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
            .authorizeRequests()     
            .antMatchers("/user/getEmployeesListRole/**")
               .access("hasAuthority('WRITE_DATA') && hasAuthority('READ_DATA')")           
                  .anyRequest().permitAll()         
            .and().formLogin().permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable();              
    }    

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin")
                                     .password("admin")                                  
                                     .authorities("WRITE_DATA", "READ_DATA");                                      
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }    

    @Override
    @Bean
    public  UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }
}`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `@EnableWebSecurity` on `Oauth2SecurityConfiguration` `@EnableResourceServer` is enough.
You should also replace `extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with `extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`.

If you want to use your `RemoteTokenServices` instance I recommend you override `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` `public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception` with

```
@Override
public void configure( ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources ) throws Exception
{
    resources.tokenServices( serverConfig.getTokenServices() );
}
```

Comment: But i am seeing ' In order to use this filter you must @EnableWebSecurity somewhere in your application,' in docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.html

Comment: @ EnableWebSecurity is needed somewhere.  That annotation conveniently creates a FilterChainProxy.  FilterChainProxy has a list of other filters related just to security.  I suspect that @ EnableResourceServer conveniently adds an OAuth filter to the FilterChainProxy created by @ EnableWebSecurity.